# Rails 3.1 and static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, static-pages

I'm just in the middle of upgrading a large application from Rails 3 to Rails 3.1 and struck a problem with my implementation of the pages controller:

```
  when templates doesnt exist
    should render the 404 page (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) PagesController automatic paths when templates doesnt exist should render the 404 page
     Failure/Error: get 'base_page_processor', :base_page => 'something_that_doesnt_exist'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `map' for "pages":String
     # ./app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:5:in `base_page_processor'
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.10557 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:36 # PagesController automatic paths when templates doesnt exist should render the 404 page
```

This did work in Rails 3.0. Something must of changed with the template_exists method. Here is the controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def base_page_processor
    view_prefix = "pages"

    if params[:base_page].present? && template_exists?(params[:base_page], view_prefix)
      render "#{view_prefix}/#{params[:base_page]}"
    else
      #TODO : Notify missing url via email error or error notification service
      render '/public/404.html', :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

Solution code:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def base_page_processor
    view_prefix = ["pages"]

    if params[:base_page].present? && template_exists?(params[:base_page], view_prefix)
      render "#{view_prefix[0]}/#{params[:base_page]}"
    else
      #TODO : Notify missing url via email error or error notification service
      render '/errors/404.html', :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

I also noticed that it wasn't rendering the error views (ie: /public/404.html) so I created a directory app/views/errors and put all the error static pages in there and just render them now. It works.

Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template_exists` method parameters indicate that the second parameter, prefix, should be an array. Normally Rails methods accept both by converting something to an array if not, so this is slightly unusual.

```
exists?(name, prefixes = [], partial = false, keys = [])
```

This method is also aliased as template_exists?

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb, line 93
def exists?(name, prefixes = [], partial = false, keys = [])
  @view_paths.exists?(*args_for_lookup(name, prefixes, partial, keys))
end
```

So making `view_prefix = ["pages"]` should work? (and modifying the remaining string interpolation accordingly)